# How to reset pose on a skinned model (Three.js)

Tags: three.js

How do I return my model (skinned mesh and bones) to the original state, before an animation has been played? In other words to unset the animation.

I've tried playing single frame "Rest pose" animation but it feels like a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Three.js r67 has a new method THREE.Animation.prototype.reset, that might just do the trick. :)